# HtmlAgilityPack extracts text from all divs in a page and not just from the one div specified in the code

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am having a strange behaviour with a xpath expression with HtmlAgilityPack.
I'm trying to use the HtmlAgilityPack to extract all the values within a div declared as 
`<div class='cont'>` However, when I use the code below I simply get all values within
`<div class='cont'>` AND `<div class='button'>`. Does anyone know why this is happening?
Here is the full code to reproduce it:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string text1 = @"<div class=""cont"">
<h3>content</h3> 
<div style=""margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt"" class=""Normal"">content1</div><div style=""margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt"" class=""Normal""> content2</div>
<div style=""margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt"" class=""Normal"">content3 </div>
<div>content4 </div><strong>content5
<div>content6 </div><ul type=""disc"">    
<div>content7 </div>        
<div>content8 </div>    </ul>
<p class='margin10'><font size=""2"">
<div>
<p><span style=""font-family: Arial"">content9</span></p>
</div>
<div>content10</font><a href=""mailto:james@polis.com""><u><font color=""#0000ff"" size=""2""><font color=""#0000ff"" size=""2""> content11 </u></font></font></a><font size=""2""> content12
<div>content13</div>
</div>
</font>
</p>
</div>
<div class=""button"">
<span class=""applybtn""><a class=""buttonGlobal buttonAlpha"" href=""/uk/job/apply/(id)/608735"">content14</a></span>
</div>";
            foreach (XPathNavigator node in SearchInPage(text1, "//div[@class='cont']"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("option " + node.Value);
            }

        }

        private static XPathNodeIterator SearchInPage(string text, string xpath)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(text);
            XPathNavigator xpathNavigator = htmlDocument.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator nodes = xpathNavigator.Select(xpath);
            return nodes;
        }
    }
}
```

The code returns:
'content', 'content1-13' PLUS 'content14' which exists within  `<div class='button'>`

Comment: You must be using a broken Html Agility Pack. My version 1.3.0.0 returns just one node wich is the main 'div' with the 'cont' class.

Comment: @SimonMourier - I am using version 1.4.0 Stable.
I downloaded and re-installed the htmlagilitypack.dll but still have the same problem. if i remove <font size=""2""> (the one right after <p class='margin10'>) from html code, then the code works fine. i.e. HAP only returns the values within <div class='cont'>

Answer (score 1):

So If I'm understanding correctly, you want to find the value only for the children nodes of node `<div class="cont">`?

Try this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument;
doc.Load(Html);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='cont']");

foreach(HtmlNode childNode in node)
{
    Console.WriteLine(childNode.Value);
}
```

I don't have a way to debug this in front of me, but this should work. the `(".//div[@class='cont']")` should select only the specified node and it's children, and ignore anything that lives outside the specified node. The rest is just Linq and HtmlAgilityPack - Remember, HtmlAgilityPack implements XPath, so make sure to look through AgilityPacks available methods before using XPath... remember that xml and html are different languages, and what works for one won't necessarily work for the other.

Comment: @gffppaste I run the following:
    `HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();`
    `doc.Load(new StringReader(text1));`
    `HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='cont']");`
    `Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);`
//used stringreader because i was getting 'Illegal characters in path' error.App still returns text from two nodes (<div class='cont'> and <div class='button'>). I tested my code (code that comes with my question) on 50 pages of the same website  and worked for 48 of them. 'text1'(see question) contains the html of 1 of those 2 pages where the code failed.